# Javaプログラムの出力結果がなぜそうなるのかよくわからない

Tags: java

以下3つのJavaプログラムを実行したとき、想定とは異なる結果になりました。

**想定していた結果:**

```
計算開始
comb(5, 0)=1
comb(5, 3)=10
comb(5, 2)=10
NegativeNumberException was thrown: -3! can't be calculated.
BadCombinationException was thrown: 5C6 can't be calculated.
計算終了
```

**実際の実行結果:**

```
:~/java$ java Comb
計算開始
comb(5, 0) = 1
comb(5, 3) = 10
NegativeNumberException was thrown: -3! can't be calculated.
```

#### 疑問点

なぜ以下の行がそれぞれ出力されなかったのかを知りたいです。お願いします。

- `comb(5, 2)=10`
- `BadCombinationException was thrown: 5C6 can't be calculated.`
- `計算終了`

---

**対象のプログラム:**

```
public class NegativeNumberException extends Exception {
    public NegativeNumberException() {
        super();
    }

    public NegativeNumberException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

```
public class BadCombinationException extends Exception {
    public BadCombinationException() {
        super();
    }

    public BadCombinationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

```
public class Comb {
    public static int fact(int n) throws NegativeNumberException {
        if (n < 0) {  // 負の数の階乗
            // エラーなので、例外を作成して投げる
            throw new NegativeNumberException(n + "! can't be calculated.");
        }
        else if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return n*fact(n-1);
        }
    }

    public static int comb(int n, int k)
        throws NegativeNumberException, BadCombinationException {
        if (n < k) {
            throw new BadCombinationException(n + " C " + k 
                                              + " can't be calculated.");
        }

        /* nCk = n!/((n-k)!k!) */
        return fact(n)/(fact(n-k)*fact(k));
    }

    /** テスト用mainメソッド */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            System.out.println("計算開始");
                    
            int result;
        
            result = Comb.comb(5, 0);
            System.out.println("comb(5, 0) = " + result);

            result = Comb.comb(5, 3);
            System.out.println("comb(5, 3) = " + result);
            
            result = Comb.comb(5, -3);
            System.out.println("comb(5, -3) = " + result);
            
            result = Comb.comb(5, 2);
            System.out.println("comb(5, 2) = " + result);
            
            result = Comb.comb(5, 6);
            System.out.println("comb(5, 6) = " + result);

            System.out.println("計算終了");
        }
        catch (NegativeNumberException e) {
            System.err.println("NegativeNumberException was thrown: "
                               +  e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (BadCombinationException e) {
            System.err.println("BadCombinationException was thrown: "
                               +  e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try-catch節で例外が発生した時点でcatch節に処理が移り、例外発生からcatch節までの正常系の処理は**実行されません。**
参考: [Javaのtry-catch文を基本から! より良いエラー処理の方法を身に着けよう](https://engineer-club.jp/java-try-catch#i)

それはtry-catch節の中から呼び出したメソッドでthrowされた例外でも上記の挙動となります。
デバッガを使ってステップ実行すると分かりやすいですが、今回は`result = Comb.comb(5, -3);`のコードから呼び出される`fact(-3)`の処理で`NegativeNumberException`例外が発生しています。
その直後に`catch (NegativeNumberException e)`ブロックに処理が移動するので

> comb(5, 2)=10
> と
> BadCombinationException was thrown: 5C6 can't be calculated.
> と
> 計算終了

を出力する処理は全てスキップされます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。とてもわかり易く理解が深まりました。